# Laravel 5 migration refuses to run

Tags: php, mysql, migration, laravel-5

I'm growing desperate, I need help! I've been at this all day!
I want to configure a DB in Laravel. I have all my migrations (in order) so no foreign key will conflict and hit a table that would only be created later.

But no matter what I try I keep hitting an error that says this,
http://prntscr.com/6z23nw
EDIT: now it says the exact same thing but that the class was 'not found'... I'm totally clueless here....

A bit more information, (I was going to post a screenshot but I can't)... searching for usages of GroupUser all I can find is the one I posted and entries in the laravel.log (listed as non-code usage). So there really is no other "groupUser" class

Here's a screenshot of my migrations folder.

[These are my migrations](http://prntscr.com/6ytvl4) they run in order and all tables until GroupUser are properly created
the migration that's causing all this mess

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class GroupUser extends Migration {

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('group_user', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('group_user');
}}
```

One final note I completely erased all the previous migrations and even tried reinstalling with the php artisan migrate:install

Comment: Could you put the exact error? You say the error is `Class 'UserGroup' not found`, but your file is named `GroupUser` perhaps it is it a filename issue?

Comment: Edit `function down()` use `Schema::drop('group_user')`

Comment: @haakym Might be that I missread it wrong, I'll double check it tomorrow when I get back to my computer. My Do thanks for pointing that out. It's a copy error.

Answer (score 0):

Run `composer dump-autoload`. After creating the migration files via artisan, you need to re-run composer to have them be autoloaded automatically.

Comment: How do I re-run composer? You mean I just do php artisan migrate after dump-autoload?

Comment: in the folder you have your `composer.json`, just run `composer dump-autoload`. Then after that runs, yes, you run php artisan migrate. If the class still isn't found check your spelling and ensure you don't have any errors there.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue,

. migrate:reset to set everything from blank
. created migrations with the tables but no foreign keys and dependencies
. php artisan migrate (all worked out fine)
. created new migrations altering the tables required with the foreign keys.
. again 'php artisan migrate'

I think it all worked fine. Thank you for your help and ideas everyone!